# How to turn homemade gelatin into powder

Tags: gelatin, marshmallow

I exracted some gelatin from bones and I want to make “Meat-Mallows” but the marshmallow recipes all call for powdered gelatin, so how much liquid gelatin is equivalent to a pack of Jell-O? Or how do I turn my homemade gelatin into powder?

Comment: I suspect that the issue will be in knowing how much gelling power is in your liquid (what they call the ‘bloom strength’) which is standardized across powdered gelatin, I think.  (Sheet gelatin comes in different strengths, and yours might be higher or lower than the typical packets)

Comment: Will your meat marshmallow contain a similar amount of sugar as the recipes using neutral gelatine? I think the sugar is important for the consistency. Your meat based gelatin will retain some meat flavor and I don't know whether you want to combine that with the usual sweetness of marshmallows.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answerable question.

> how much liquid gelatin is equivalent to a pack of Jell-O

This depends on the concentration, and you don't know it. It's probably not even worth trying to measure it, as I suspect that it will differ quite a bit between batches.

> how do I turn my homemade gelatin into powder

This is probably doable, but not easy. You'd have to explore some kind of homemade vacuum dryer, as a dish of bone extract in a normal dehydrator would be roughly equivalent to a lab incubator for bacteria. But the more important part is that this won't help you further, because removing some water from your self-made gelatin won't let you standardize its binding strength in any way.

If I were you, I'd use the homemade extract for less sensitive applications, maybe some kind of aspic, and follow the meat-mallow recipe without any substitutions.